# I am getting error while trying to check orientation of app?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I have trying following code but it displays error message:

```
driver.rotate(org.openqa.selenium.ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE); 
Thread.sleep(5000); driver.rotate(org.openqa.selenium.ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Error message:-

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Please share Appium server logs. If you take a look at the correct step, there might be more information as to why the generic `An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.` message is shown. It's possible that either the app or the device is locked to a certain orientation.

Comment: @Domestus : Thanks for reply..  The above test case have passed while  i have manually change screen orientation. But it failed while keeping device stable. Error log appium server:-info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Set the orientation, but app refused to rotate."}

Comment: Why the app screen doesn't rotate automatically..I just stuck

Comment: There seems to be a solution to the `"Set the orientation, but app refused to rotate."` error message. Your problem could be related to the fact that the app relies on the sensor to do rotation and doesn't allow the user to set it. This was the case for "maxski" at least: https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-set-the-orientation-but-app-refused-to-rotate/3200/3

`"The problem was in Android app code. Devs should set orientation reliance to user not to censor."`

Comment: I have checked with Dev, they set orientation=Full sensor, that's why my test case fails. but i have checked same test case twitter app, test case executes successfully. Is any solution on it?? please provide me solution...

Comment: @Domestus : Thank you , My problem solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a solution to the `"Set the orientation, but app refused to rotate."` error message. Your problem could be related to the fact that the app relies on the sensor to do rotation and doesn't allow the user to set it. This was the case for "maxski" at least: https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-set-the-orientation-but-app-refused-to-rotate/3200/3

`"The problem was in Android app code. Devs should set orientation reliance to user not to censor."`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to identify orientation is portrait or not.
    public boolean Method_isCurrentOrientationPortrait(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AppiumDriver driver) {
        String ort = driver.getOrientation().name();
        ScreenOrientation orientation = ScreenOrientation.valueOf(ort);

```
    if (orientation == ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT) {
        System.out.println("Current screen orientation is portrait");
        return true;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Current screen orientation is Landscape");

        return false;
    }
}
```